# When asked the running time of a certain algorithm, should you go with the worst case scenario?

Tags: big-o

I was curious as to what you should answer when asked the running time of a algorithm.  For example, if you are asked the efficiency of an algorithm such as a bubble sort algorithm, should you give the answer O(n), the best case, or O(n^2), the average and worst case?

Comment: You usually want the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its an interview, having the ability to explain average use case and worst case is usually asked for. Unless the interviewer asks you to tell you the best case - which is rare.

Because having the intuition to explain an algorithm's worst or average case gives a glimpse into your general knowledge of algorithms.